# In Excel, sum all values in one column in each row where another column is a specific value

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm wondering if there is an easy way to do what I'm looking for. Basically, I have a balance sheet in Excel 2011 with a bunch of data. One specific piece of information I always want visible is the amount that hasn't been reimbursed. In other words, I have a column for the amount paid and another for whether or not it has been reimbursed (Yes/No). I want to sum all of the amounts paid where the reimbursed field is equal to 'No'.

I recognize I can sum the entire column and filter out those that have been reimbursed, but I'd like it to display the full amount regardless of what filter is on (or if no filter is on).

I wasn't able to find good keywords to describe this to Google, so I'm asking here. I would like to accomplish this in Excel, not in an external program or script.

Answer (score 114, accepted):

If column A contains the amounts to be reimbursed, and column B contains the "yes/no" indicating whether the reimbursement has been made, then either of the following will work, though the first option is recommended:

```
=SUMIF(B:B,"No",A:A)
```

or

```
=SUMIFS(A:A,B:B,"No")
```

Here is an example that will display the amounts paid and outstanding for a small set of sample data.

```
 A         B            C                   D
 Amount    Reimbursed?  Total Paid:         =SUMIF(B:B,"Yes",A:A)
 $100      Yes          Total Outstanding:  =SUMIF(B:B,"No",A:A)
 $200      No           
 $300      No
 $400      Yes
 $500      No
```

[image: Result of Excel calculations]

Comment: The second formula works for Google spreadsheet also. First one did not work for it somehow...

Comment: Stacks never let's me down.

Comment: One bit of clarification.  That criteria can be an expression, function, wildcard, etc.  , e.g. ">32", TODAY(), "*es", or even something like: =SUMIF(A2:A6,">" & D4,B2:B6)

Answer (score 18):

You could do this using `SUMIF`. This allows you to SUM a value in a cell IF a value in another cell meets the specified criteria. Here's an example:

```
 -   A         B
 1   100       YES
 2   100       YES
 3   100       NO
```

Using the formula: `=SUMIF(B1:B3, "YES", A1:A3)`, you will get the result of `200`.

Here's a screenshot of a working example I just did in Excel:

[image: Excel SUMIF Example]

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use the IF function for that. the syntax is `=IF(condition, value_if_true, value_if_false)`. To add an extra column with only the non-reimbursed amounts, you would use something like:

```
=IF(B1="No", A1, 0)
```

and sum that. There's probably a way to include it in a single cell below the column as well, but off the top of my head I can't think of anything simple.